# iCal (or other?) Formatting for Abstract Recurrence

Tags: c#, .net, calendar, icalendar, schedule

I have a need to store recurring patterns of events in a way that is independent of the notion of a specific date/time -- i.e., the pattern is not a exactly a recurring "event" which occurs within a specified window. Specifically, to answer questions such as: when is an establishment open for business, or when may deliveries be made to that establishment.

**An example might be: every Monday, Wednesday, and Thursday, from 10:00 to 12:00, and also Wednesday from 2:00 to 4:00.**

In the past I have created database tables with structures specific to storing this type of data -- i.e., tables which define these "time windows" with multiple rows per establishment, for each type of window needing description. I want to get away from this method, however, and on to something more modern -- a parse-able format, of which iCal would appear to be the most likely candidate. I would like suggestions for alternatives, however, if there is something better.

I've looked into the nuts & bolts of how to express iCal repeating patterns, and must say that while I grasp the rudiments, I can't quite yet see how I'd actually go about formatting a single iCal "event" for the example I posted above, i.e.: **no particular start/end date, no specified number of occurrences, etc.**

I'd love some guidance on this, and to see a specific example, if someone can formulate it for me. My platform is, generally, .NET/C#, MSSQL, Outlook/Exchange.

Comment: Maybe you should look at sparse matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a new iCalendar extension that describes these windows called `VAVAILABILITY`:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7953

Comment: oooh, nice! That is great. I do think I am going with iCalendar as my solution. I'll mark this as my solution, but I am wondering: do you know enough about iCal that you could present an example of what it would look like -- at least a snippet of the correct format?

Comment: The actual RFC actually contains a number of samples. Take a look at the appendices.

Answer (score 1):

For your specific example, you might look at using a CRON expression syntax for the start time and then include a duration field.  CRON is pretty powerful for recurrence patterns, but you likely would also need some way to exclude dates (for holidays for instance).  I've been using ncrontab for a recent project and it works great for parsing and occurrence determination.

https://github.com/atifaziz/NCrontab

You would still likely be in the situation of building a custom database structure for your needs, but one option you could look at is adding a column in your DB and store a serialized JSON string instead of several separate tables.  SQL Server 2016/Azure SQL can natively query JSON too.

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes, as an old UNIX fart, I thought about crontab as a possible solution, and it's not a bad one. My conclusion has been that crontab isn't quite flexible enough for what I need. I'd also prefer to adhere to a "standard" that is potentially portable for use in a variety of applications (e.g. various calendaring systems). I do rather like the notion of a JSON stream... That's a good idea there. The stream could self-define the format. I've just recently started using the built-in utilities in .NET/MSSQL for JSON-based ETL & parsing.